# How to change REST Api Key from parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

*(Regardless weather parse.com will be shutdown in 11 months, we still use it unless we found an alternative)*

For an external developer we had to hand out the REST API Key.
Now, after he finished his work, we want to close the possibility to him to download all the data again and again.
Just to recreate the master key isn't a solution because the REST API is still working for him (at least for read-requests).

Is there any possibility to lock him out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. REST API key is public information and not a secret and cannot be hidden. If he can download all the information this means you chose to make information public. Technically everyone will be able to download the data as long as you have public ACL/CLPs